# Which of the nicotinic acetylcholine receptors (nAChRs) catalyse the release of the neuromodulators mentioned below that's caused by nicotine?

Tags: neuromodulation

**Neuromodulators:** acetylcholine, norepinephrine, epinephrine, vasopressin, histamine, arginine, serotonin, dopamine, autocrine agents, and $\beta$-endorphin.

I am aware that agonists of the $\alpha_7 $ nAChRs improve cognition in Schizophrenia, presumably by catalysing the release of histamine, norepinephrine and/or acetylcholine.<sup>1,2</sup> I also know that $\alpha_7 $ nAChRs antagonists reduce $\Delta^9$-tetrahydrocannabinol (THC) self-administration in mice presumably by suppressing dopaminergic activity in the nucleus accumbens or by inhibiting the activity of the CB<sub>1</sub> receptor.<sup>3</sup> Selective CB<sub>1</sub> antagonists also manage to reduce nicotine dependence.<sup>4</sup> Also I know that the activation of the $ \alpha_3 \beta_4 $ nAChRs in the adrenal medulla catalyses an epinephrine and norepinephrine release.

---

### Reference List (Oxford Style)

1. M Hajós, BN Rogers, '[Targeting alpha7 nicotinic acetylcholine receptors in the treatment of schizophrenia.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19909231)', *Current Pharmaceutical Design*, 16/5 (2010), 538-554.
2. LF Martin, WR Kem, R Freedman, '[Alpha-7 nicotinic receptor agonists: potential new candidates for the treatment of schizophrenia](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00213-003-1750-1?LI=true)', *Psychopharmacology*, 174/1 (2004), 54-64.
3. M Solinas, M Scherma, L Fattore, J Stroik, C Wertheim, G Tanda, W Fratta, SR Goldberg, '[Nicotinic α7 Receptors as a New Target for Treatment of Cannabis Abuse](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/27/21/5615.full.pdf)', *The Journal of Neuroscience*, 27/21 (2007), 5615-5620.
4. C Cohen, E Kodas, G Griebel, '[CB<sub>1</sub> receptor antagonists for the treatment of nicotine addiction.](http://ggriebel.perso.worldonline.fr/Pub87.pdf)', *Pharmacology, Biochemistry and Behavior*, 81/2 (2005), 387-395.